# Column-wise "outer-product"

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a `20 x 10` matrix `X`, and I want to create a `10 x 10 x 20` array `A` with `A[i,j,] = X[,i] * X[,j]` for `i,j` in `1:10`. Here is a simple solution using a `for` loop:

```
X <- matrix(seq(10*20),20,10)
A <- array(dim=c(10,10,20))
for (i in 1:10)
  for (j in 1:10)
    A[i,j,] <- X[,i] * X[,j]
```

How do I implement this with vectorization?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `outer`, is this what you want?

```
A2 = array(apply(X, 1L, function (x) outer(x,x)), dim=c(10,10,20))

# test
X <- matrix(seq(10*20),20,10)
A <- array(dim=c(10,10,20))
for (i in 1:10){
  for (j in 1:10){
    A[i,j,] <- X[,i] * X[,j]
  }
}

all.equal(A, A2) # TRUE
```

**EDIT:** updated answer after question example in question was changed.

Comment: I've edited my question so `X` has all unique entries. The point is to do the column-wise outer-product on any general matrix.

Comment: `i,j` should be `ncol(X)`, which in this case is `10`.